# How to lower large equipment down the basement stairs

Tags: safety, tools

I'm expecting a new member of the shop family to arrive soon and as any expectant father I'm worried about delivery.

I have a 250lbs+ band saw that needs to be lowered down a single flight of stairs into the basement, and I'm trying to figure out the best approach to doing this.

I'll update this with a diagram shortly.

Comment: +1 to the beer/pizza/friends/moving (though not in that order). It helped me and my cabinet saw to have a couple of 2x4s nailed to the stairs to act as a skid surface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Back it down with a stair walker:

[http://www.amazon.com/Capacity-Appliance-Truck-Stair-Climber/dp/B00O39FJ2S/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1454178497&sr=8-3&keywords=stair+dolly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O39FJ2S)

Comment: A lot of times you can rent these too. The delivery driver may have one. The uhauls near me have them for rent. These are the tool for this job. You can usually also hire a guy from a local moving company for an hour if you have the money and don't feel you can do it safely on your own, they generally have these tools.

Comment: I hired the local "Two Men and a Truck".  They came, they saw, they conquered, and 10 minutes later I was in the basement taking apart the crating for my brand new super-duper table saw.  Cost me $100 - too much, but the job was done quickly and painlessly.

Comment: I did this myself with a tablesaw. Not down stairs but up into a box truck and back down into a new garage. Moved a 200 lb bandsaw last week. I took the top half off and it helped a good amount in preventing it from being top heavy.

Answer (score 4):

Some friends and a case of beer moved my entire shop from the garage to basement.

Comment: friend - n. 1. A device used to efficiently convert beer and pizza to mechanical energy.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who was a single guy until recently, who didn't want to bother my friends with my latest purchase, I moved every single tool I own into the basement on my own.   From table saw to 6" jointer, bandsaw, etc.

I've moved things two ways.  First, if it's in the box, I could easily slide the box down the step one at a time (they're carpeted).  When the box was too large or difficult to even GET to the steps, I took the pieces out and carried them down one at a time.  The heaviest was probably the bed of the jointer, and I placed that on a cardboard box and slid just that piece down the steps.

Now, going up might be a different story...

Answer (score 1):

My solution for bringing a (still boxed) cabinet saw down into the basement via the bulkhead stairs was two people above slowly letting out ropes arranged for 2x mechanical advantage as it slid down the stairs plus myself underneath guiding and providing additional support. It worked, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it. Should have unboxed and brought it down in pieces, probably.

Since then I too have been looking for a better way to rig tackle for this purpose. In Theory it ought to be possible to arrange a crane setup, but I haven't yet found an answer I like.